# Py4JJavaError error while fatching data from mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pyspark

I'm trying to load data from MongoDB by `pyspark` but it is giving me errors,
This is my code

```
# Loading the training data from mongodb into a dataframe
df_train = spark.read.format('mongo')\
    .option('spark.mongodb.input.uri','mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Quake.quakes').load()

df_train.show(5)
```

[Error One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ26p.png)

[Error Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKfhp.png)